# jQuery .add() and empty()

Tags: jquery, jquery-post

```
<div id="msg_container">
  <span> Is this helpful ? </span>
  <span class="feedback"> 
     <a title="like"> Yes </a> 
     <a title="dislike"> No </a> 
  </span>
</div>

// jQuery Script
$('.feedback a').live('click', function() {
   var reference = $(this).parent().parent();
   $.post("URL", $("FORM").serialize(),
        function(data){
    // posted successfully and following will be executed
    reference.empty();
            reference.add('<span> You have given feedback </span>');

   }, "json");       
});
```

The process would be:

1. User will be asked 'Is this helpful? Yes No'
2. Upon clicking either 'Yes' or 'No', .post method will be executed
3. After posting to server successfully,
4. I want the DOM element id="msg_container" to change entire content to a normal span or paragraph with the sentence 'You have given your feedback' so that each user can only give one feedback.

The problem:

1. Once the div "msg_container" it's emptied, the .add() didn't work.
2. Even without emptying the "msg_container', the .add() still didn't work.
3. I read the documentation, the .add() doesn't seem to work with reference object just like I did above.
4. I have to assign the reference to variable as such var reference = $(this).parent(); Otherwise, after executing $.post, the $(this) will lose its original 'this' reference.

Any idea how to solve this? I can accept alternative solutions as long as my requirement is fulfilled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `append()`

```
reference.append('<span> You have given feedback </span>');
```

Comment: +1. `add()` adds the given element into the current jQuery working set; it doesn't do DOM manipulation.

Comment: Hi @Thariama, I feel shame for overlooking. I totally forgot that I could use .append()

Moreover, I've already used .append() for other part of codes some more. Anyway, a great thanks for that ! :)

Comment: @Interrobang Thanks for confirming that part. I kinda read it, but wasn't too sure. :)